# R package install: using locally installed libraries

Tags: r, installation, rggobi

In particular I am trying to install rggobi locally on linux (I don't have root access). So I installed ggobi locally

```
cd ggobi-2.1.11/
./configure --prefix=~/my-apps/ --with-all-plugins
make
make install
```

That went fine. Then I tried

```
$ R CMD INSTALL /tmp/Rtmp2PL6au/downloaded_packages/rggobi_2.1.20.tar.gz -l ~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/
* installing *source* package ‘rggobi’ ...
** package ‘rggobi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GGOBI... no
configure: error: Package requirements (ggobi >= 2.1.6) were not met:
No package 'ggobi' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GGOBI_CFLAGS and GGOBI_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rggobi’
* removing ‘/apps/infrafs1/rdahiya/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rggobi’
```

I tried adding ~/my-apps/lib/pkgconfig/ in PKG_CONFIG_PATH which helped the installtion go little further but at the end it gives different error

```
building package indices
testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rggobi/libs/rggobi.so': libggobi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
removing ‘~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rggobi’
```

libggobi.so.0 is there in ~/my-apps/lib/. Any suggestion how to make R to look at correct place?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a (the?) work around. I have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/my-apps/lib/ while installing or  while running any future R session where I want to load rggobi. Please share if you have more clean solution.